How to set GIS point as destination in MoveTo Block in Anylogic
Why can I not choose an Agent GIS Point in the MoveTo Block?
Screenshot of what I see
I have played around and choosing a GIS point as a destination only works in the main palette, but I do not get to make it work in any of the other agents.
Is there a different block that I need to use to move agents between locations outside of the main agent palette?


Why can I not choose an Agent GIS Point in the MoveTo Block?

Because it only lets you select stuff on the same agent type. Your GIS network likely sits on Main and your agent with the yellow house is embedded into Main.
In such a case, you need to use code to access Main, likely main.myNode will do the trick (use code-complete).
Here is the basic concept that you need to understand VERY well: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to
